# Stud finder reading detecting metal in very large area above window

Tags: electrical, wiring, walls, drill

When I use my stud finder on its "metal" setting above any of my upstairs windows, it shows the entire area above the window as being metal.

On other walls the stud finder works as expected.

I was wondering what might be causing this reading, and whether it would be safe to drill holes to hang a curtain rod.

[Here is a video of the reading I am getting](https://photos.app.goo.gl/b2UatT1BDwRXmLR16)

Comment: What does the finder show when set on WOOD?

Comment: Could be expanded metal lathe was used to reinforce plaster (https://www.trussforte.com.au/collections/rendalok), could be there's a metal HVAC duct in there... a photo would help. Also measure wall thickness there. Also use an ordinary magnet to test if that *is* a large area of ferrous metal.

Comment: Many windows have lintels above them to take the load of the wall above, many of those lintels are made of metal - especially in some countries.